# Programming logic behind Temple Run (OpenGL ES ?)?

Tags: android, ios, graphics, opengl-es

I am very much facinated by the success of Temple Run (iOS and Andriod) developed by 2 developers and 1 artist.

My questions are -

What did they use for graphics rendering, was it OpenGL ES for the whole game (right from display to player movement) ?

Also how can HTML help in creating such dynamic game ?

Does the same core engine works in iOS and Android (but both are two different languages - Objective C and Java) ?

I am not thinking of creating a game myself but I have been thinking on this for few days and searched various posts on web - but could not find satisfatory answer.

Can anyone please help me understand. Thanks.

Comment: I think this question should be directly mailed to the developers of game..because all other can just assume nothing much.

Comment: Please ask the same question on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/